# Thoughts on PHP w/ web sockets vs. integration with node.js or total site in node.JS

Tags: php, node.js

I'm going to be developing a website that uses a fair amount of push data, social feeds, chats, etc. I've been reading a few articles about integrating node.js with an existing PHP architecture and it seems that people are saying this is more efficient than a PHP based web sockets solution.

I'll take input on the above mentioned, but mainly I'm looking for advice on doing a PHP/node combination vs. doing the whole website in node.js

Articles talking about node's immaturity are what make me want to stick with PHP for logins/session control/URI routing and other main functions... but the other part of me thinks that serving the whole website in node would accelerate the whole website

Comment: You can always use both (with node essentially providing a websocket wrapper and performs curl calls to the php solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming question. This is a risk assessment question:

PHP: low risk, less performance.

Node.JS: high risk, better performance.

Can you afford the high risk? If you can't the answer is simple: use PHP. If you can afford it and you're willing to invest and take a risk you can try Node.JS. If it's too risky, maybe there is another project you could use Node.JS for?

You can also implement in PHP first and switch to Node.JS later when you understand the performance characteristics more.